# Visual Studio 2022 for Mac no startup templates?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm a longtime user of Visual Studio on Windows, but decided to try out Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. I didn't get very far, because it seems the startup project templates are missing. Were these present on previous versions of VS for Mac? Do these need to be installed separately? Or maybe not available at all?

[image]

Comment: MacOS does not support "Windows Forms Applications". This is only available on Windows devices. However, if you download a Virtuel machine and run Windows on it, you will be able to see Windows Forms applications on it.

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT I understand that some of the templates that specifically target the Windows environment will not be available on the Mac version, but shouldn't the cross platform templates (like .Net Core) be available?